# Flutter Image Picker Validator

Tags: flutter

I am trying to add a validator to image picker but I see that it does not work with form validation.

How can I add a validator to my image picker to ensure that it is required before proceeding to the next screen?

Code for selecting from gallery/camera and uploading to firestore

```
final imagePicker = ImagePicker();
 String url = '';

 File? file;
 void imageSelectFromGallery() async {
   final image = await imagePicker.pickImage(
     source: ImageSource.gallery,
     preferredCameraDevice: CameraDevice.rear,
     imageQuality: 100,
     maxWidth: 5000,
     maxHeight: 5000,
   );

   setState(() {
     file = File(image!.path);
   });
 }

 void imageSelectFromCamera() async {
   final image = await imagePicker.pickImage(
     source: ImageSource.camera,
     preferredCameraDevice: CameraDevice.front,
     imageQuality: 100,
     maxWidth: 5000,
     maxHeight: 5000,
   );
   setState(() {
     file = File(image!.path);
   });
 }

 void uploadFile() async {
   var imageFile =
       FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('path').child('/.jpeg');
   UploadTask task = imageFile.putFile(file!);
   TaskSnapshot snapshot = await task;
   // for downloading
   url = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
   await FirebaseFirestore.instance
       .collection('users')
       .doc(uid)
       .collection('Verification')
       .doc('Identification')
       .set({'Image URL': url});
 }
```

onPressed:

```
onPressed: () async {
           uploadFile();
           Navigator.push(
             context,
             MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => VerificationPage2()),
           );
         },
```

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/form_builder_image_picker

```
FormBuilderImagePicker(
        name: 'photos',
        decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Pick Photos'),
        maxImages: 1,
  validator: (v) {
            if (v == null) {
              return 'Please upload your picture ?';
            }
          },
           onChanged: (imagePath){
            //code
           },
   ),
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).